# Art VS Nature (What is the impact)

Tags: environmental-impact

I live near a nature reserve, it is a combination of moors, fields and forests.  (containing animals like deer, snakes, frogs, foxes, sheep, goats, cows and a large variety of bugs)

But since last week there is a new "art-project" that has the local community in an uproar, mainly because it looks like they just ditched trash in the area...

Is there a valid environmental concern? Are there arguments i can bring towards the organizer of this "art" project to halt it? seeing this is going to continue for another 3 months.

Art in question:

A giant ball made of sugar and food coloring.
[[image: sugarball1]

The engine of an old oil ship:
[image: ship-engine]

a "ship-wreck"

[image: ship-wreck]

I hope this is the appropriate Stack exchange site, otherwise i would love a referral to one where this question is better suited.

Comment: Have you asked the management of you nature reserve, what steps have been taken in order to ensure there is no negative environmental impact? Will the art be completely removed after the 3 months?

Comment: @Erik send him a mail yesterday, am invited to his office tomorrow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today i had about an 2 hour long conversation with the local park ranger.

He assured me that all measures are made to make sure that the environmental impact is kept to a minimum. But he also said that there was a limit to what they could do, their budget only covers about 80% of what is needed to keep everything going on a year to year basis and they are forced to allow such things (by the local government) to increase their funding...

At least the worst exhibits were blocked...one with tonal music and one with flashing lights seeing they would upset the fauna to much. Also the giant sugar ball is getting removed due to a high number of insect deaths.

Comment: Good work! I was curious, is that ball sugar *all the way through?* Seems like that would be expensive -- I assumed it was some sort of hollow ball with a sugar coating.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the results of your follow-up!

Comment: @LShaver actually it is solid concrete, covered in about 1 cm layer of sugar. But the rain already washed a lot away.